# B2B web service using windows credentials?

Tags: web-services, windows-authentication

Is this wise, what potential issues could you run into?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to be a bit more specific. This question is fairly unwieldy and a lot of assumptions would need to be made to give you a straight answer.

Are you talking about managing authentication/authorization with LDAP or AD?

Or are you talking about using the kerberos key generated when you login to authenticate with a web app, and that webapp uses that key to pass along to a web service?